# How can I mute player in chat by admin?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I working on my game now I'll start build chat page.

I need to know how I can mute any player by admin but the problem not here because I created `IsMute Variable (Boolean)` on FireStore inside profile player but the problem how I can add duration for mute any player.

*I have this document when mute any player*

Chat (Collection)

Auto ID for example F8429483 (Document)

1. Name (String inside F8429483)
2. HisMessage (String inside F8429483)
3. Reason (String inside F8429483)
4. Duration (TimeStamp inside F8429483)

The main question: Can I add timestamp by server time rather than mobile time?

The second question: Is there any simple code has compared the time until I know if it is over duration or not.

There is no code by me because I don't have any idea for how I can do it. I'm using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I add timestamp by server time rather than mobile time?

To write the server-side timestamp, use `ServerValue.Timestamp`, such as in this snippet from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects):

> ```
> docRef.update({
>   timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
> });
> ```